# Is there ever a situation where you ever need a primary key with 32 fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is admittedly a "Friday" question..
When I look up [the definition of](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20primary%20key&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=define%20primary%20key&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=off) "primary key" it says :

> In Oracle, a primary key is a single field or combination of fields
>   that uniquely defines a record. None of the fields that are part of
>   the primary key can contain a null value. A table can have only one
>   primary key. In Oracle, a primary key can not contain more than 32
>   columns.

Why would one ever need 32 columns in a primary key? Is that ever a situation that comes up?

Comment: composite keys come up frequently. but a 32field primary key would be incredibly painful, especially in a foreign key situation. your child tables would also have to have all 32 fields listed, which just gets... stupid.

Comment: @MarcB - Maybe to test out the computer's CPU though? Like for performance testing purposes?

Comment: @Coffee . . . Oracle decided there had to be a limit, so they made it 32 (there is probably an underlying technical efficiency for this).  I myself avoid composite primary keys, so I only rarely ever need more than one column.

Comment: 32 Primary key fields sounds... horribly, "Enterprisey"

Comment: @coffeee: there's better ways to test performance than creating a franken table with 32field PKs. DB servers do need good cpus, but throwing a 32field PK franken table at the cpu would make no difference at all v.s. a 32field non-PK index, etc.. After all, a PK is simply a unique index that is guaranteed to be a unique ID of any particular record. but other than that, it's just an index like any other.

Comment: Most DB designers will just use sequences as primary keys - they are much more efficient, cannot be null and ensure uniqueness.

Comment: It is very odd design. To say at least.... You really need a surrogate  primary key for such scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primary key is backed by an index, and [an index key can only have 32 columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF53989). So it's an inherited restriction from the index. There probably wasn't much point adding additional restrictions on the primary key itself, as the index may exist before the primary key constraint, and can persist if the constraint is removed.

There are [other constraints on the primary key](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52198) which don't necessarily apply to the index itself.

The 32-column limit for an index is presumably related to how they are implemented (as Guffa says), and there isn't much point asking why they picked 32 instead of 16 or 64 or whatever. It's *slightly* more reasonable to have a 32-column index than a 32-column primary key, but I'd imagine it's still pretty unusual. That a primary key could theoretically also have 32-columns doesn't really imply you'd ever come across one in the wild.

To answer your questions: you wouldn't; and no. (Someone will now say they used to work on a system that did do this...)

Answer (score 1):

It can be the case having a fact table in the star Schema with as much dimensions. The fact record would be identified by Dimension keys. Having said that, I don't really think this would make sense to physically create such a constraint. You usually can control uniqueness in your ETL-Processes and this fact table would never be a parent in some parent-child relationships

Answer (score 0):

Limits like that is set depeding on how much space can reasonably be assigned for it, how much would possibly be needed, and how often you would need a lot of it.

In this case you are not really supposed to reach the limit. It has been set at a level where you would normally never even get close to it. There has to be a limit for it, but there was obviously no need to keep it low, so it's an arbitrary number that isn't so large  that it wastes space.